Chrome and Edge reset connection when a client certificate is used
I am trying to connect to a website that uses an SSL certificate, when the attempt does not include the certificate installed on the local machine in the current user, the connection is successful but, when the user's certificate is selected, through the certificate selection dialog box, the connection is reset by the internet browser, chrome and edge but not Firefox.
The only alternative that allows selecting a certificate and connecting to the website is to use Microsoft Edge in Internet Explorer mode.
The reproduction of both cases is the following:

Connection cancelled.

a. type the address of the website and return
b. select a certificate through the certificate selection dialog box.
c. the internet browsers show the message can't reach this page and the message ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
If, in this case, you click on cancel in the certificate selection dialog box, the site is displayed normally but the validation and authentication with the appropriate certificate is lost.

Successful connection.

a. Enter the website address and return
b. Select a certificate using the certificate selection dialog box.
c. Internet browsers display the message can't reach this page and the message ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
d. Only in the case of Microsoft Edge, activate the (...) Reload in Internet Explorer mode option.
e. The certificate selection dialog box is displayed again. Select the certificate, if there are several, or simply click OK.
f. The website is loaded and the home page is displayed.
Only Firefox connects to the site without any warning or problem, only the certificate is selected, when there is more than one, if there is only one, Firefox connects directly without asking for any kind of selection.
Is there some kind of new requirement in Chrome and Edge that causes this situation?

This is one of those "why" questions that require asking the developers of those browsers and thus is not a good question for Stack Overflow. I can only guess that the Chrome developers considered keeping a connection open while waiting for a user to ponder a certificate dialog and make a selection to be a tie-up of precious server-side ports whereas the Firefox developers did not.

This problem occurs when the web site is configured to use TLS1.3, HTTP/2, client authentication certificates, and provides support for the post_handshake_auth TLS extension.
The impacted browsers perform the TLS handshake without issue, but the client certificate is not requested by the server until after the handshake is complete.  If the client does not support post handshake authentication, the connection is forcibly reset.
Resolution:
Chromium-based agents have no plans to provide support for the post_handshake_auth TLS extension.
To mitigate this issue, the server needs to conduct the request for client certificate during the TLS handshake procedure.
For example, HTTP.SYS has a flag named ClientCertNegotiation that is disabled by default but can be enabled for IIS site bindings per the following article:
Netsh http commands: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-http#add-sslcert

Unfortunately I have followed the suggestion but the problem persists, the connection attempt is reset (cancelled).
